# Change max_heap_table_size value?

Tags: mysql, memory-table

There's a max_heap_table_size limit to 16 mb so how can i change this value and where?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am pretty sure the max_heap_table_size is set to around 16MB by default. So I would first check what it is set to by running a query:

`select @@max_heap_table_size;`

And then you can run a query to set it higher:

`set @@max_heap_table_size=NUMBER_OF_BYTES;`

Answer (score 18):

In case you cannot change your heap value try this

Add this to mysql/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

this will cover mysql restarts. To set these values in mysqld right now without restarting run this:

```
SET GLOBAL tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
SET GLOBAL max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
```

If you are checking the above variables with

```
SELECT @@max_heap_table_size;
```

you may notice that they don't seem to change following the `SET GLOBAL...` statements. This is because the settings only apply to new connections to the server. Make a new connection, and you'll see the values update.